# Can I sell pre-built LEGO sets?

Tags: sets, shopping, glue

So I was interested if it would be legal to sell LEGO sets that were built by me. Most likely on some sort of website whether it be my own or one like eBay or craigslist. Specifically:

- Could I make a profit legally if it isn't MOC?
- Would it be against any form of copyright?
- If they were to be glued together would that be an issue?
- If I were to make my own website but make credit to LEGO what would be the implications?

Comment: Ofcourse, millions of people are doing that. However, note that I personally would never intentionally buy a glued set and that I strongly prefer any 2nd hand set I buy to be disassembled.

Comment: To add on to what @MichaelVerschaeve said: if your sets are glued, expect to see much diminished returns from selling. Glued sets are (with very minor exceptions) not appreciated in the LEGO community, The exception being LEGO store displays which contain sets that are factory glued.

Comment: If you have a local unofficial LEGO store, they probably have pre-built sets for sale.  They may also take sets on consignment.  https://bricksandminifigs.com/store-locator/ are definitely offering pre-built sets for sale.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can sell used LEGO sets. In fact there is huge market for such sets due to, relatively, high product value even on second-hand market. People use local classifieds for local sales as well as global platforms like eBay, Bricklink for greater exposure.

> Could I make a profit legally if it isn't MOC?

It is worth noting, some used sets tend to sell for much higher value than they cost when were new. This is caused by demand, and usually because set being some kind of "special". So yes, you can make a profit.

> Would it be against any form of copyright?

You can sell pre-owned vehicles, electronics, household items and this is known to be a norm. How is selling used LEGO different from this?

> If they were to be glued together would that be an issue?

Yes, you need to state your model is glued, as it is expected that LEGO model/set can be disassembled for parts.

> If I were to make my own website but make credit to LEGO what would be
> the implications?

You need to follow [LEGO Fair Play](https://www.lego.com/en-us/legal/notices-and-policies/fair-play/#:%7E:text=In%20the%20LEGO%20Group%2C%20we,copying%20and%20other%20infringements%20easily.) and you'll be alright.